# Matching jQuery and jQuery-UI versions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I understand that jQuery and jQuery-UI versions do not perfectly match up.

For example, the current "safe" version of jQuery is 1.11.2 and the current "safe" jQueryUI is 1.10.4

Sometimes a client requirement is to continue using a specific version of jQuery, such as 1.8.3. I would like to use the "newest" version of jQuery-UI that will work with that specific version of jQuery core.

Is there a document somewhere that maps the latest version of jQuery-UI that will work with a given version of jQuery core?

Comment: The most latest Jquery UI will work with JQuery 1.8.3 .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, I finally noticed this datum. On

http://blog.jqueryui.com/

the current version of jQueryUI is documented: new features, changes, etc.

Quite a bit down the page, the .0 release of the current version is documented, [and includes this section](http://blog.jqueryui.com/#post-1247):

```
**Supported jQuery Versions and Browsers**
jQuery UI 1.11.0 supports jQuery 1.6 and newer. That’s 25 versions!
```

Comment: I would recommend checking the dependency listed in the jQuery-UI [`bower.json`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/bower.json) file for this info. Even the current master branch (`1.12.0-pre`) states it's jQuery requirement as `>=1.6`. Following the typical semantic versioning scheme, any version in the `1.x` range higher than `1.6` will work fine here. :)

Comment: I still wonder how to update the version of jQuery that jQueryUI is using. I just downloaded jQueryUI and it's pointing to a very old v1.12.4 version. But I have also downloaded jQuery 3.1.1.  How can I update jQueryUI to use that version? I notice the jquery.js file that jQueryUI points to has other stuff in it. Any best practices on how to use a different version of jQuery with jQueryUI? Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

According to [Jquery Blog](http://blog.jqueryui.com/2016/09/jquery-ui-1-12-1/):

**Dropped jQuery 1.6.x support**: jQuery UI 1.12 officially supports jQuery 1.7.0 – 3.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who needs to know the compatibility of jQuery UI with jQuery, jQueryUI 1.13 ( most recent as of today ) supports all jQuery versions ( from 1.8 upto 3.6 - most recent ).

Comment: Isn't this pretty much exactly what [Greg Brasswell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559418/1873386), directly below yours, already says?