# Jquery, Jquery UI - version sync required?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kentico

I'm working on a legacy project so my options for changing Jquery and Jquery UI versions is limited. I cannot change the UI version that I am aware of and I cannot go higher than Jquery 1.11.0. (Project is in Kentico 7)

I've found an interesting "thing" in regards to syncing up jquery and jquery ui. It would appear that when I use Jquery 1.11.0 and Jquery UI 1.8.24 and then implement a tab widget, it pukes at me in the console (specifically when changing tabs). Syncing them up to 1.8.2 and 1.8.24 makes this problem go away but this is the first time I've seen a need to sync the two versions.

In researching this, I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370169/matching-jquery-and-jquery-ui-versions) but it doesn't seem to answer it for me (or maybe I just can't make heads or tails out of the information).

*Is there indeed a problem between Jquery 1.11.0 and UI 1.8.24 or am I using the wrong code implementation for the tab widget as listed in the Jquery UI site for 1.8?*

Edit: because it looks like I should not be having this problem, I am including the code that I'm using...

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js"></script>
....
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Manage States</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Manage Countries</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Manage Zip Codes</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="fragment-1">
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2">
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="fragment-2">
        ...
        </div>
        ...
        <script>
            //set the tabs to be tabs
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            ...
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you planning to suppot IE-8 and below versions, if not then you can look for sync to Jquery 2.0., http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I cannot upgrade jquery beyond 1.11.0 because it's a legacy project in Kentico 7. Doing so will break the whole site.

Comment: In the jQueryUI wikipedia entry it lists the compatibility history: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI#Release_history

Comment: Hmm.... so this makes me wonder what the problem is. The code runs fine when they're synced up but the problem I'm experiencing, if I'm reading that correctly, should not exist. Does that seem like the conclusion I should be drawing to you?

Comment: @MetalPhoenix couldn't you just implement the newer version of the jQuery library on the page(s) you need and disable the older version the same way?  Seems like a webpart macro should be able to handle this.  

Also I don't believe your version of Kentico has anything to do with it unless you are using the Kentico jQuery library.  If that's the case, then you should be able to remove that and use the newer reference.

Comment: @BrendenKehren: This would be a solution if we were working in a small section but eventually we're going to migrate this behemoth site into this new data paradigm so, if I understand you correctly, I'm not entirely sure that that would be a scalable option. For now, we're syncing up the two versions because jquery 1.11 vs 1.8.23 isn't that big of a difference for what we're doing. Unfortunately, this might just be a work-around for a code problem instead of a library problem.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix yeah I wouldn't recommend it for anything other than a temporary fix.  Moving forward, using the jQuery library outside of Kentico is a lot easier than it was in the past so keep that in mind when moving to 8.x or 9.

Comment: Good to know. It doesn't look like we'll be upgrading the kentico version anytime soon but I will remember that for the future. Thanks again.